# speed-up python function to process files with data segments separated by a blank space

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I need to process files with data segments separated by a blank space, for example:

```
93.18 15.21 36.69 33.85 16.41 16.81 29.17 
21.69 23.71 26.38 63.70 66.69 0.89 39.91 
86.55 56.34 57.80 98.38 0.24 17.19 75.46 
[...]
1.30 73.02 56.79 39.28 96.39 18.77 55.03

99.95 28.88 90.90 26.70 62.37 86.58 65.05 
25.16 32.61 17.47 4.23 34.82 26.63 57.24 
36.72 83.30 97.29 73.31 31.79 80.03 25.71 
[...]
2.74 75.92 40.19 54.57 87.41 75.59 22.79

.
.
.
```

for this I am using the following function. 
In every call I get the necessary data, but I need to speed-up the code.

Is there a more efficient way?

**EDIT**: *I will be updating the code with the changes that achieve improvements*

**ORIGINAL:**

```
def get_pos_nextvalues(pos_file, indices):
    result = []
    for line in pos_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            break
        values = [float(value) for value in line.split()]
        result.append([float(values[i]) for i in indices])
    return np.array(result)
```

**NEW:**

```
def get_pos_nextvalues(pos_file, indices):
    result = ''
    for line in pos_file:
        if len(line) > 1:
            s = line.split()
            result += ' '.join([s [i] for i in indices])
        else:
            break
    else:
        return np.array([])
    result = np.fromstring(result, dtype=float, sep=' ')
    result = result.reshape(result.size/len(indices), len(indices))
    return result
```

.

```
pos_file = open(filename, 'r', buffering=1024*10)

[...]

while(some_condition):
    vs = get_pos_nextvalues(pos_file, (4,5,6))
    [...]
```

**speedup** = 2.36

Answer (score 2):

not to convert floats to floats would be the first step. I would suggest, however, to first [profile your code](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) and then try to optimize the bottleneck parts.

I understand that you've changed your code from the original, but

```
values = [value for value in line.split()]
```

is not a good thing either. just write `values = line.split()` if this is what you mean.

Seeing how you're using NumPy, I'd suggest some [methods of file reading that are demonstrated in their docs](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput#head-8b33b550a3efcb0981f6720ba42677720325588c).

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading every character exactly once, so there isn't any real performance to gain.

You could combine strip and split if the empty lines contain a lot of whitespace.

You could also save some time initializing the numpy array from start, instead of first creating a python array and then converting.

Comment: change 

    «line = line.strip();
        if not line:»

for 
    
    «if len(line) <= 1:»

empty lines only have '\n'

Answer (score 1):

try increasing the read buffer, IO is probably the bottle neck of your code

```
open('file.txt', 'r', 1024 * 10)
```

also if the data is fully sequential you can try to skip the line by line code and convert a bunch of lines at once

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
if len(line) <= 1: # only '\n' in «empty» lines
    break
values = line.split()
```

try this:

```
values = line.split()
if not values: # line is wholly whitespace, end of segment
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) doesn't work for you?

```
arr = fromfile('tmp.txt', sep=' ', dtype=int)
```

Comment: I was looking for an efficient way to read each segment of data to str and use numpy.fromstring

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant that *might* be faster for few indices.  It builds a string of only the desired values so that `np.fromstring` does less work.

```
def get_pos_nextvalues_fewindices(pos_file, indices):
    result = ''
    for line in pos_file:
        if len(line) > 1:
            s = line.split()
            for i in indices:
                result += s[i] + ' '
        else:
            return np.array([])
    result = np.fromstring(result, dtype=float, sep=' ')
    result = result.reshape(result.size/len(indeces), len(indeces))
    return result
```

This trades off the overhead of `split()` and an added loop for less parsing.  Or perhaps there's some clever regex trick you can do to extract the desired substrings directly?

**Old Answer**

`np.mat('1.23 2.34 3.45 6\n1.32 2.43 7 3.54')` converts the string to a `numpy` matrix of floating point values.  This might be a faster kernel for you to use.  For instance:

```
import numpy as np
def ReadFileChunk(pos_file):
    chunktxt = ""
    for line in pos_file:
        if len(line) > 1:
            chunktxt = chunktxt + line
        else:
            break

    return np.mat(chunktxt).tolist()
    # or alternatively
    #return np.array(np.mat(s))
```

Then you can move your indexing stuff to another function.  Hopefully having `numpy` parse the string internally is faster than calling `float()` repetitively.

Comment: I was trying something like this, but was looking for a more efficient way of reading chunks of data to go by concatenating line by line. I use np.fromstring instead of np.mat, I needan an array and make a reshape is not expensive. But let numpy parse the string it's definitely a substantial improvement.

Comment: return np.array(np.mat(s)) is more expensive than using no.fromstring

Comment: So np.fromstring + reshape is faster than np.array(np.mat(s))?  Ah well.  I learned something new, at least, I thought np.fromstring was for binary data packed into a string.

Comment: new answer run at a similar speed but I like it more because frees me from the worry about future change of the line size(7 now)

Comment: upss... I voted for this answer again but stackoverflot put 0 and don't let me vote again :(. I need a deep read of the faq.